# Answered question, author removed question

Tags: discussion, support

I am new here and I just wanted to get some reputation so I went ahead and answered this guys question:

[CSS Focus code does not work when switching to HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690195/css-focus-code-does-not-work-when-switching-to-html-5)

At first he didn't provide enough information and others told him so, after providing the information I went ahead and answered it using jsFiddle, he was using :focus where he should of been using :hover.

He didn't accept my answer and just removed the question, I don't know why he would do this but it is pretty annoying, I am only new and he's one of the first questions I answered myself.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Don't give up. Persist. Yes, questions can be deleted (provided there aren't any answers with *positive votes on them*) but there will be others you can answer.

Comment: Voted to undelete.

Comment: As a side note, I saw, you answered most of your questions yourself and accepted the answer. Its not forbidden, but you better try to answer other questions if you want to get some reputation.

Comment: I only answered my question because it sent me email telling me I had unanswered questions and I wanted to help others but okay thanks

Comment: Be patient, you'll be more annoyed when you will give the only correct answer, asker will accept it, and after few days unaccept without reason and any comment. Don't worry, s-happens :)

Comment: I sympathize, but that's not a very good question, and, personally, had I seen it undeleted I'm afraid I would have voted to close and (eventually) delete. There's thousands of other questions that need answers, though! I'm sure you can find another one to answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everybody is free to delete his own questions unless somebody's answer already has a positive score. That being said, I don't think it's particularly nice what the OP did.

In general, a moderator *can* undelete a self-deleted question, although I imagine this is rather rare. But if the only problem was using `:focus` where `:hover` was appropriate, there's a good chance that the question was too localized, and it would be closed and eventually deleted anyway.

Too many deleted questions (including self-deleted ones) can get a user question banned, so the OP won't be able to do this very often. This is automatic and requires no human intervention.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing the OP deleted the question after realizing there was nothing wrong with that code. Maybe your answer made him realize that, maybe he did it on his own.

Either way, since you invested some effort on an answer, he could at least have posted a comment clarifying the situation, and explaining that he was about to delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the community moderators undeleting a question, 10k users on the site can also view and vote to undelete a deleted post.

Considering the circumstances, it looks like 3 10k+ users casted an undelete vote and have [undeleted the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690195/css-focus-code-does-not-work-when-switching-to-html-5). This now means that the post is visible on search engines for the benefit of other visitors with a similar problem, and it means that other Stack Overflow users who see value in your answer can upvote it.

As far as accepting answers, this is completely up to the asker. No one can force an asker to accept an answer, and contacting the person about it is discouraged.

If it helps, 2 upvotes is 20 reputation points, which exceeds the 15 points gained from an accept, so if you post a really awesome answer that gets 10 upvotes, you'll never miss the accept.