# One notification about new answers should block the other one

Tags: bug, notifications, new-answers

I was answering a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141389/answered-question-author-removed-question), but I was distracted from something else. As result, somebody else  answered the question, and I got a notification on the top of the page, with a link to load the new answers. There was also a notification on the page saying there was a new answer.

I clicked on the notification on the top of the page, and up-voted the new answer that appeared. The notice on the page didn't vanish. I thought it really meant there were two answers, and I clicked on that notice too.

As result, I obtained this.

[image: screenshot]

<strike>The notification on the top of the page should refresh the page, when I click on the link to load new answers; in that way, the other notification given in the page right after the question (the one given even if you are not writing an answer) should vanish. Naturally, the refresh should not be done if I am still writing my answer.</strike>
One notification should avoid the other one is given, or the last clicked notification should not add the same answer that was already shown, as it happened in this case.

PS: Now there are two answers, but the second one is too recent to be the one who caused the notification about on new answers given after the question body to appear.

Comment: I suspect that the notification at the top should not have appeared at all, but there is a race condition or similar in the detection code that disables that feature if inline notifications can be shown. I sometimes see the bar at the top when posting an answer myself; it'll briefly tell me that there is a new answer before the page reload completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happened to me (and made me post this [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141401/new-answer-showed-twice) as I was not aware of your question), but I think that's actually a bug (a very minor bug, yet annoying).

I don't agree the solution is to make the notification click trigger a page refresh. In my case, I was writing an answer as I saw that happen, and it's useful to glance at new answers to see if I'm not repeating something already posted. Refreshing the page could have made me loose my draft.