# New answer displayed twice

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The message about a new answer being posted should refresh the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141396/the-message-about-a-new-answer-being-posted-should-refresh-the-page)

I was answering [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292/167534), as I saw two new answer notification pop up in quick succession. When I clicked them to see the answers, I noticed they were both the same answer (same Post ID, as it could be seen from their edit links). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

After refreshing the page, the duplicate was gone. Looks like a minor UI bug - but still a bug.

Comment: Dupe of [The message about a new answer being posted should refresh the page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141396) perhaps?

Comment: Those things happen. I got the notification bar "A new answer has been posted while you were answering" once, milliseconds after I had clicked "Post Your Answer". But it was just my own answer. No other answers were given! Well, these things happen.

Comment: @Martijn Yes, except that kiamluno posted that as a feature request, and I'm considering it a bug.

Comment: @bfavaretto: same issue, slightly different tags. That's arguing over semantics, while still duplicating effort, isn't it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, I'm voting to close too.